# How do you execute a teardown if an assert fails?

Tags: unit-testing, xunit.net, autofixture

I'm building some integration tests, and one of them is testing transactions.  I intentionally added a **Commit** to force the assert to fail.  However when this occurs, execution stops and my teardown is never executed (which should remove the added record).

How can I setup this test so that the added record is always deleted, even if the assert fails?

```
using (var uow = new UnitOfWork(context))
{
    //Arrange
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    var anonEmail = fixture.Create<string>("email");

    //Act
    uow.UserRepository.Insert(new DAL.Models.User()
    {
        Email = anonEmail,
        FullName = fixture.Create<string>()
    });
    uow.Save();
    uow.Commit();  //intentionally added to force Assert to fail!
    uow.Rollback();

    //Assert
    var user =
        uow.UserRepository.Get(x => x.Email == anonEmail).FirstOrDefault();
    Assert.True(user == null);

    //Teardown
    try
    {
        uow.UserRepository.Delete(
            uow.UserRepository.Get(x => x.Email == anonEmail).FirstOrDefault());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: In xUnit.net, your test class can implement IDisposable to implement Fixture Teardown: https://xunit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Comparisons

Comment: In my example I've added an anonymous string.  Other methods in the same class would have other anonymous types, so I can't see any simple and clean way of handling the tear down in a single dispose method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
//Arrange
var uow = new UnitOfWork(context);
var fixture = new Fixture();
var anonEmail = fixture.Create<string>("email");
try
{
    //Act
    uow.UserRepository.Insert(new DAL.Models.User()
    {
        Email = anonEmail,
        FullName = fixture.Create<string>()
    });
    uow.Save();
    uow.Commit();  //intentionally added to force Assert to fail!
    uow.Rollback();

    //Assert
    var user =
        uow.UserRepository.Get(x => x.Email == anonEmail).FirstOrDefault();
    Assert.True(user == null);
}
//Teardown
finally
{
    uow.UserRepository.Delete(
        uow.UserRepository.Get(x => x.Email == anonEmail).FirstOrDefault());
}
```

Comment: Odd.  I tried that before.  Maybe I put the reset in the catch statement.